# WPF DataGrid binds to string.Length instead of string text

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, datagrid

I'm new to WPF, and am genuinely trying to figure out as much as possible by myself...

I've created my first DataGrid control, and I am trying to populate it with a list of strings as below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataGridTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}">
        <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="500"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

Private Sub DataGridTest_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim StringCollection As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        StringCollection.Add("Test")
        StringCollection.Add("Test1")
        StringCollection.Add("Test2")
        StringCollection.Add("Test3")
        StringCollection.Add("Test4")
        MyDataGrid.DataContext = StringCollection

    End Sub
```

However, it actually populates with a heading "Length" and values as the length of the strings. Why is it not populating with the string values, themselves?

It's clear that I'm missing something fundamental here, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `DataGrid` by default auto generates columns from given item class so it will search for properties in `String` class that it can convert into column. You can avoid that by creating your own column and turning off `AutoGenerateColumns`

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ... AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Something"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Or just use a `ListBox` for a single column of strings - unless you need a header or something special.

Comment: @lc. or use `ListBox` but it's not clear if OP wants to edit item or not as it changes if you need `ItemTemplate` or simple `DisplayMemberPath` is enough and it's also not clear it OP wants column header or not.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I was using the above code for a learning exercise - the final control will be used for editing.