# Load a simple array to DataGrid in WPF - DataGrid shows only the length of each item

Tags: c#, wpf

Based on what I have read online binding to an array shoud be as simple as setting the `DataGrid.temsSource` property to point to the array but when I do that I only see the length of each item in the array.

Here is what I have...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTesting"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="hobbiesDataGrid" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="138" Width="360">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace DataGridTesting
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string[] hobbies = new string[] { "Computers", "Cars", "Photography" };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.hobbiesDataGrid.ItemsSource = hobbies;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> **Length**
>   9
>   4
>   11

What I'm expecting to see in the first column is

> **hobbies**
>   Computers
>   Cars
>   Photography

What am I missing? How can I properly show the items in the array on the first column of the DataGrid?

Comment: There's a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556613/wpf-datagrid-binds-to-string-length-instead-of-string-text) that should help and explain why this is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your grid up to not autogenerate columns as there is no context in the array.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="128" Width="273" Margin="76,94,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hobbies" Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Also notice the ItemsSource is set to binding and Binding is set in the DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: FYI - Use `Binding="{Binding Path=.}"` if you use double click events on a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use string array directly.

Check the below code:

```
        DataTable hobbies = new DataTable();
        hobbies.Columns.Add("hobbies");

        hobbies.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Computers" });
        hobbies.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Cars" });
        hobbies.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Photography" });
```

Then use it like before:

```
        this.hobbiesDataGrid.ItemsSource = hobbies;
```

All is explained here: http://www.psworld.pl/Programming/BindingListOfString

Comment: Glad it was useful.